# The function 'uigetfile' is not supported for standalone code generation

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to convert matlab code into c++ code using matlab coder but I am getting this error:

> The function 'uigetfile' is not supported for standalone code
>   generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you
>   can use this function in simulation.

Is there any alternative for uigetfile?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest refactoring your code so that you select a file and such like in C++ (that is, code it yourself) then call the Matlab code with the file and such like as parameters.